# Trying to call Wikipedia api using React, but getting a useless object back

Tags: reactjs, wikipedia-api

I am trying to search to wikipedia from my input, and it was working but all of a sudden no longer does. This is my call to wikipedia, but data when I console.log it I get the response down below.

```js
const fetchResults = async () => {
        const url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=extracts|pageimages&pithumbsize=400&origin=*&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=${searchQuery}`;
        await fetch(url)
            .then(data => {
                loggingContext.addLog(data);
```

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&act…plaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=dog", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "cors"
url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=extracts|pageimages&pithumbsize=400&origin=*&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=dog"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: ""
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong? Or maybe I simply made too many calls? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `json` (or `text`) on the result to get the data. These two functions return Promises, so make sure to await them. (or use .then, since you started with await in your code I've decided to use just await)

Example (using loggingContext):

```js
const res = await fetch(url);
const data = await res.json();

// data is your data.
loggingContext.addLog(data);
```

Example snippet:

```js
async function wiki() {
    const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=extracts|pageimages&pithumbsize=400&origin=*&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=dog';
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();

    document.getElementById('response').innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
}

wiki();
```

```html
<pre id="response">
Loading...
</pre>
```

Comment: @GrimmKracker Could you check again, I'm 100% sure this exact code works.

Comment: @GrimmKracker I have attached a snippet showing this definitely works.

Comment: So weird, I swear I set it up exactly like you have it and it didn't work earlier. Now it's functioning just fine when I re-wrote it (my understanding of promises also aren't that great), so maybe I've just been staring at my project too much today haha. Thanks.

Comment: @GrimmKracker Promises are really easy to understand, you schedule something to begin and then give it a callback to call when it ends.